# Batch rename -- multiple image types

Tags: scripts, batch-rename

I have a large number of images that I copied from a failing external hard drive. All of the images are fine and have no corruption, but oddly a large number of them are now missing extensions. The files are a mix of jpg, png, and gif, and are named in the following structure, all in a single folder.

```
1
2
3
4.jpg
5.png

etc
```

Some files have extensions, while many do not and are just the numbers. There are roughly 4000 images in this folder, so manually renaming is not an option.

Is there any script or program that can be used to determine the extension via meta-data and add it to the files as needed?

I have used "pyrenamer" from the software center for years for renaming files, but it doesn't appear to be able to add extensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my coding sucks and I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: How exactly did you copied them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below a python solution (script). 
The script uses the [imghdr module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imghdr.html) to recognize the file type. It will add the correct file extensions (if missing), of the following types:

```
rgb, gif, pbm, pgm, ppm, tiff, rast, xbm, jpeg, bmp, png
```

If the file already has a file extension, it will be skipped. In case the file is of an unknown file type (if it is damaged for example), the file is reported as "could not  determine":

```
could not determine: /home/jacob/Bureaublad/picturetest/blub
```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import imghdr
import shutil

directory = "/path/to/pictures"

for name in os.listdir(directory):
    # combining file+its directory:
    file = directory+"/"+name
    # only files without a dot are subject to renaming (else the file already has a file extension or is a hidden file):
    if name.count(".") == 0:
        # fetch the file extension from the file:
        ftype = imghdr.what(file)
        # if it is impossible to get the extension (if the file is damaged for example), the file(s) will be listed in the terminal window:
        if ftype != None:
            shutil.move(file, file+"."+ftype)
        else:
            print("could not determine: "+file)
```

Paste it into an empty file, save it as rename.py, set the directory to the pictures in the `directory = "/path/to/pictures"` -line and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/rename.py
```

#### Rename recursively

In case your images are not in a "flat" directory, but in a layered directory, use the version below. It will check (and repair if necessary) file extensions inside the file's current folder.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import imghdr
import shutil

directory = "/path/to/pictures"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        file = root+"/"+name
        if name.count(".") == 0:
            ftype = imghdr.what(file)
            if ftype != None:
                shutil.move(file, file+"."+ftype)
            else:
                print("could not determine: "+file)
```

Comment: works but it replaces the file which has it's extension available already. That is `foo.png` becomes `foo.png.png`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I corrected a small mistake, but it should not have any effect on what you mention, everything below `if name.count(".") == 0:` only happens if there is no dot in the name (either invisible or with extension) so it seems impossible that *anything* happens when there is a file extension already. That is in line with what I tested.

Comment: +1, could you explain each code by commenting..

Comment: This does works (just tested). Earlier however, I cheated by shorting all files in Nautilus by MIME type, and oddly enough all affected images missing the extension were .jpg. Drive crash effected the files copied off in a strange way. I cut those images to another folder and used Pyrenamer to add the .jpg extension, then moved them back.

Answer (score 2):

Simple script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for file in ~/path/to/images/*; do
    TYPE=$(file --mime-type -b "$file" | cut -f2 -d/);
    if [[ ! $file =~ \.$TYPE ]]; then
        echo mv -v "$file" "$file.$TYPE";
    fi
done
```

#### Explanation of `TYPE=$(file --mime-type -b "$file" | cut -f2 -d/);` (finding file type)

find the extension of each `$file` using `file`(determine file type) command.

`--mime-type, --mime-encoding` option  used for print only the specified element(s).

`-b, --brief` option used for do not prepend filenames to output lines (brief mode).

See also **[man file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/file.1.html)** for more info.

Now we extracted the file type and saved it into `TYPE` variable.

**And what is `cut -f2 -d/` command?** This used for printing just extension type, Like `png` in `image/png` output from `file --mime-type -b "$file"` result.

`-f2` prints second part with `/` delimiter(`-d` option) between fields. ex: Print `png` in `image/png`.
See also **[man cut](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cut.1.html)** for more info.

#### Explanation of `if [[...]];` (checking file extension)

We skipped all existing extension with a simple regex, using the `=~` operator inside a `[[...]]` test in if condition:

```bsh
if [[ $file =~ \.$TYPE ]];
```

While `$file` is your images filenames and `$TYPE` is its extension which we found and stored that into `TYPE` variable in `TYPE=$(file --mime-type -b "$file" | cut -f2 -d/);`.

Then we skip to rename all files that has an extension with themselves.

`!` refer to: if file has NO extension with itself, then rename that and add its extension at the end of its name.

#### Explanation of `echo mv -v "$file" "$file.$TYPE";`(rename step)

In this line Actually we are appending the file extension(if `$file` doesn't an extension with itself) at the end of `$file` file by using `mv` command. `mv` also using for renaming Files/Directory.

Then we rename `$file` to `$file.$TYPE`. For example file `1` will be rename to `1.png` if its file type was `png` format.

```
in theory actually above mv command do this: rename filename -> filename.filetype
```

That filename stored into `$file` variable and filetype stored into `$TYPE` variable.

#### How can you use this script?

Copy and paste the script in [`gedit`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) and save it with your favorite name ex: `batchRename`, then open Terminal and run it by the following command:

```bsh
bash batchRename
```

DON'T forget before running script verify your correct images path `/path/to/images/` and for renaming on your files after checking the result with `echo` command, remove `echo` from the beginning `echo mv -v "$file" "$file.$TYPE"` and run the script again and enjoy renaming ;)

Comment: Hi KasiyA, take care; it "corrects" my `.jpeg` into `.jpeg.JPEG`. why not skip all existing extensions?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have updated including skip all existing extension and explanation for each line. Thank you

Comment: BTW, I wasn't the person who downvoted.

Comment: I tried it, it works fine on `.jpeg`, but my `naamloos.bmp` is renamed `naamloos.bmp.x-ms-bmp`

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't know the OP's question just said jpg,gif and png btw you can add `|cut -f3 -d-` after `|cut -f2 -d/` to fix that :)

Comment: Ah, I see, he indeed only mentioned jpg, gif and png.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner using the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/.*/use File::MimeInfo::Magic qw#mimetype extensions#; sprintf("%s.%s", $&, extensions(mimetype($&)))/e' * -vn
```

it's using the Perl `File::MimeInfo` module to query the file (sort of how the `file` command does) to work out what the file is and then to append the first extension MimeInfo has for that MIME type back onto the file.

In some cases this can result in less commonly used extensions being used (like jpeg or jpe for what most people would name jpg files) but you can do a second pass to correct these quite easily:

```
rename 's/\.jpe$/.jpg/' *
```

But most applications won't mind if you specify .jpe files so this isn't necessary most of the time.

Both `rename` commands above are set in test mode.
They won't do anything until you remove the `-n` argument from the end.

Comment: `e` (modifier) at the last helps to execute the code which are present in the replacement part.

Comment: Yup, normally a `s/a/b/` would literally replace `a` with `b` but here, it evaluates the replacement side allow you to do fancy things like this.

Comment: but it replaces the file which has it's extension available already. That is `foo.png` becomes `foo.png.png`