# Correct file extensions

Tags: files, file-format

I have about 12000 images of different file types but every one of them was renamed *.jpg.

Now I want to give them their proper extensions back, how can I do it

Comment: recursively, or in a "flat"  directory?

Comment: Similar questions [How can I rename files/change their extensions based on mimetype with a script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/575070/178692) and [Batch rename — multiple image types](http://askubuntu.com/questions/539282/batch-rename-multiple-image-types)

Comment: @steeldriver pretty close, but those files don *not* have an extension, here they have *the wrong* extension.

Comment: @JacobVlijm that's why I didn't flag the question as a duplicate: however the methods proposed in the *answers* have value here, IMHO

Comment: @steeldriver I completely agree.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it relatively easily in bash:

```
for f in *jpg; do 
    type=$(file -0 -F" " "$f" | grep -aPo '\0\s*\K\S+') 
    mv "$f" "${f%%.*}.${type,,}"  
done
```

This is the same idea as @A.B's answer but using shell globs instead of `find`. The `${f%%.*}` is the filename without its extension. The `-0` of the `file` command makes it print a `\0` after the file name which we then use to `grep` the file type. This should work with arbitrary file names, including those that contain spaces, newlines or anything else. The `${type,,}` is a trick to get lower case extensions. It would convert `PNG` to `png`.

You didn't say in your question, but if you need this to be recursive and descend into subdirectories, you could use this instead:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*jpg; do 
    type=$(file -0 -F" " "$f" | grep -aPo '\0\s*\K\S+') 
    mv "$f" "${f%%.*}.${type,,}"  
done
```

The `shopt -s globstar` will enable bash's globstar option which lets `**` match subdirectories:

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or  more  directories and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: @A.B. see update. It allows `**` to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Those semicolons at the end of each line are redundant, aren't they?

Comment: @PaddyLandau yes, I was testing it as a one liner and added newlines for clarity here. I forgot to remove them. Note that they're not wrong, just redundant as you say.

Comment: Great, although `file` does not always specify the extension it seems: it's turning a bash file into `foo.bourne-again` here for instance!

Comment: @Campa no, of course not. It would also add bogus extensions to binary files, normal text files, perl and python scripts and the list goes on. The question was asking about _images_ specifically and those do tend to have the same name as their usual extensions. Remember that extensions on Linux are optional, with very few exceptions, they don't actually do anything. They help the user organize their data, the OS doesn't care about them.

Answer (score 12):

The script below can be used to (recursively) rename an incorrectly set extension, `.jpg`, to the correct one. In case it finds an unreadable file, it will report it in the script's output.

The script use the `imghdr` module, to recognize the following types: `rgb`, `gif`, `pbm`, `pgm`, `ppm`, `tiff`, `rast`, `xbm`, `jpeg`, `bmp`, `png`. More on the `imghdr` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imghdr.html). The list can be extended with more types, as mentioned in the link.

As it is, it specifically renames files with the extension `.jpg`, as mentioned in the question. With a minor change, it can be fit to rename any extension, or a specific set of extensions, into the correct one (or with no extension, like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/539300/72216)).

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import imghdr
import shutil
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        file = root+"/"+name
        # find files with the (incorrect) extension to rename
        if name.endswith(".jpg"):
            # find the correct extension
            ftype = imghdr.what(file)
            # rename the file
            if ftype != None:
                shutil.move(file, file.replace("jpg",ftype))
            # in case it can't be determined, mention it in the output
            else:
                print("could not determine: "+file)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rename.py`
2. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rename.py <directory>
   ```

Comment: +1 for simple and easy to read, unlike the bash based solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer will soon be obsolete as [`imghdr` will be removed in Python 3.13](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html)

Answer (score 3):

*Note: My approach seems to be too complex. I would prefer terdons answer in your place.*

---

You can use the command `file` to to determine the file type:

```
% file 20050101_14-24-37_330.jpg 
20050101_14-24-37_330.jpg: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2, baseline, precision 8, 1200x1600, frames 3

% file test.jpg
test.jpg: PNG image data, 1192 x 774, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

With this information, the files can be renamed:

***Please do a test before you apply the command to your images***

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} file -F"<separator>" {} | 
 awk -F " image data" '{print $1}' | 
  awk -F"<separator> " '{
   system("mv \""$1"\" $(dirname \""$1"\")/$(basename -s .jpg \"" $1 "\")."$2)
   }'
```

---

Example

```
% find . -type f -name "*.jpg"
./test.jpg
./sub/20050101_14-24-37_330.jpg

% find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} file -F"<separator>" {} | awk -F " image data" '{print $1}' | awk -F"<separator> " '{system ("mv \""$1"\" $(dirname \""$1"\")/$(basename -s .jpg \"" $1 "\")."$2)}'

% find . -type f -iname "*"    
./test.PNG
./sub/20050101_14-24-37_330.JPEG
```

Comment: Note that this will break in the unlikely case that any of the file name contain newlines.

Comment: @terdon Yes, I've been thinking. Unfortunately I have no idea what I can do. Can you help?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this properly using awk. It's not the right tool for the job. Either use `find -exec bash -c "..."` and do everything in there or use `while read -d '' name type` to split the file name and `file` output and then parse `$type` to get the file type. Not worth it really, see my answer for how to do it much more easily in pure(ish) bash.